# How to properly select AR, MA, or ARMA structure for time series data?

Tags: arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I am attempting to model seasonal and diel changes in fish depth over time. Previous work has used ARMA correlation structures, which makes sense logically. I have processed my data to weekly means of all tagged fish (11) with a single mean for each diel period (day/night). With just over a year of data, I have a total of 1302 data points.

My model looks like

```r
M1.lme <- lme(depth ~ season*PSR, random = ~ 1|animal_id, 
              data = StatisticalDataDepthWeek)
```

where PSR denotes diel period, and season denotes season.

ACF and PACF plots are included below.

[image]

[image]

How do I interpret these graphs? I cannot find any similar examples in the literature or online

Comment: I would try ARMA(1,1) ...

Comment: I would plot the raw series first to see what's happening informally.